# Approximation by measure with finite support

Tags: measure-theory

Can a Borel probability measure on a Polish space be arbitrarily approximated in the total variation metric by a probability measure with finite support?

Comment: Assuming you mean "finite support" literally, the support is a finite set, then no, not even close. If $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$ then $||m-\mu||=2$.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant _bounded_ support in which case the answer is yes for trivial reasons.

Comment: @Ullrich. Yes, I meant that the support is a finite set. Thanks for your answer (if I understood correctly, the $\mu$ in your argument is a probability measure on $[0,1]$ with finite support).